# Reputation changes also to inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, notifications, global-inbox

I would like to see my reputation changes in the StackExchange inbox as notifications. I have several accounts on different StackExchange sub-portals and it annous me to watch time by time if the reputation has changed at any of them.

I have to admit that I am little bit addicted to see my reputation changing..

Comment: High-rep users would have notifications all the time

Comment: Not so long ago reputation wasn't updated in real time... I kinda miss that.

Comment: @YannisRizos Me too.  It might not be terrible to have your rep number at the top with a little indicator if there have been changes since your last visit, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [December 2013 top bar redesign](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/), there is a new inbox for “achievements” next to the inbox for useful notifications. Achievements are mainly reputation changes and badges.

Comment: Nice memories, I forgot this already. Now in present I see I have what I had in dreams since then. Hmmm.. I would questionize the amount of downvotes today..

Comment: are you overwhelmed with rep change notifications on the new top bar, as was stated? Or anyone with high rep?

Comment: @mico I tended to leave them unread for a while — it's a bit annoying when the number of digits changes but otherwise it's just a green blur and fortunately the number of digits tapers off logarithmically. The really annoying thing is when I accidentally open the box after clicking the inbox and moving the mouse a bit too far right. Now I hide them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189142/can-we-keep-basic-site-notifications-from-showing-up-as-unread-notifications-in/235053#235053

Comment: @mico And yes, I am overwhelmed — I get far more achievements changes than inbox changes, and I don't care about them.

Answer (score 15):

No, please not; my inbox would be overrun with notifications.

Use one of the notifiers listed on http://stackapps.com instead, I use [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-mac-os-x) myself (on Mac).

Comment: Does Newt still notify you of reputation changes? Mine stopped doing that a month or so ago (it still notifies of new questions though)

Comment: @Clive: It does.

Comment: OK, time for a reinstall methinks. Thanks

Comment: I use SOStacked now on my iDevice and I am ok with that.