# Can we keep basic site notifications from showing up as unread notifications in our inbox?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox

When I log on and see a number in the upper left on my screen, I immediately think that someone has answered one of my questions or commented on something else I posted.  Most of the time, it just turns out to be a generic site notification telling me that one of my questions got a lot of views, that it's a "nice question", or that I've earned a badge.

I don't care about these notifications.

Is there already a way to completely ignore these?  I don't even want to know about them.  All I want to know about are answers to my questions or when someone comments on my questions, answers, or other comments.  If such a feature does not exist, can it be considered?

**Edit**

Some are saying that these notifications show in a different color.  This is *not* the case.  When I have a mix/match of any combination of notifications, this is what I see:

[image]

The only time this is ever a different color is when I am on an entirely different SE site (gaming, DIY, overflow, super user, etc).  Within the same site, though, I never see different colored numbers indicating that I have 2 responses to an answer I posted, 1 badge notification, and 1 notification telling me my question is nice.

Comment: My suggestion: Use another colour. (Badge and permission notifications are already blue rather than red; make these yellow or something?)

Comment: Personally, I'd rather not see them at all.  Unless it's a permission notification, they serve zero practical purpose.

Comment: I thought they already *were* a different color. The only red notifications I ever get are "you have received an answer" and "you have received a comment reply". Boy do I get a lot of the latter...

Comment: I see the same as Cody, can't see an issue here - do you *really* get so many badges etc?

Comment: The badge and other site notifications are a different color from the inbox notifications, so you can probably make them disappear with some custom CSS.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: You can see a red notification [in the screenshot here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/show-inbox-updates-in-the-page-title). That is the usual color for new inbox messages/answers.

Comment: @sth:  Correct.  No one's saying otherwise.  However, it differs per SE site, but you still only see one color.  I don't know where everyone else is getting the idea that there are different colors.  There are not.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin. ??? The screenshot I linked to and your screenshot here in the question are both from meta.SO. My screen shot has a red notification, yours has a blueish one. What exactly is your point?

Comment: @sth: My point is that the new notification icon is different per SE site. On this meta, it a sort of light blue circle. On Stack Overflow, it's a red circle. It's done that way to match the current SE site's color scheme. However, what you will not see are different-colored notification icons within the same SE site.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: No, **both screen shots are from the same site** (meta.stackoverflow.com) and they show different-colored notification icons. I don't know how it can be any more clear than that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there already a way to completely ignore these?

No there is no currently implemented way of doing this. 
Yes, badge notifications are annoying but they are displayed in another color so there is no way to think that :

> I immediately think that someone has answered one of my questions or commented on something else I posted.

Now, as you progress through the site (I'm not sure at what point exactly though) you will earn more reputation and notifications you get all the time from common bronze badges will stop showing up in the notification bar. I agree they are annoying... but just be patient you will stop receiving *some of  them* someday.

Comment: What do you mean by different color?  See edit to my question for screencap.  As for being patient, I don't think so.  I use 4 or 5 SE sites on a regular basis and each one has its own badge award tracking.  I've been on SE for a few years now and am still getting badge notifications.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin It's not about time. It's about reputation on the site. you don't have more than 2.5K anywhere. I think you need more than that.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd [If you have 200+ rep on any associated account, you don't get notified about (most) bronze badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/191706). You always get notified about silver and gold badges.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Thanks cound't find that page !

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: Reagrdless, "waiting it out" is not a good solution, imo.  Also, please answer my question about about the different colors.  See my edited question for screencap.

Answer (score 2):

Since the [December 2013 top bar redesign](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/), useless notifications such as badges and reputation gains (“achievements”) are in a separate inbox (green indicator) from useful notifications such as answers and comments (red indicator).

You can remove the achievements inbox with a bit of CSS. For example, with Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)), you can use this style to make it disappear:

```
@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("stackapps.com") {
    .icon-achievements {
        display:none !important;
    }
    .icon-achievements-unread {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```