# Optional Android notifications for reputation changes

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, android-app

I would like to get a notification if my reputation count has changed. I think there is already some internal API for that. (I can see that changes in the menu bar in the top).

I'm sure that some people would not like that so that should be optional.

Comment: i would love that one.

Comment: me too me too, believe it.. :P :D

Comment: This is already visible when you view your profile page. If there is a number beside the reputations tab, it will indicate the change in reputation since you last viewed your reputation breakdown. Sure you don't receive a notification, but it's an indication of what changed.

Comment: @Werner - He is talking about an *Android notification* for reputation changes.

Comment: @Werner well that is correct but I don't have the app all time opened, in this case a notification would be more helpful.

Comment: @rekire You're right. Like we have in facebook and hangout apps for android devices

Comment: We don't have such notifications in browser version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reputation changes also to inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142962/reputation-changes-also-to-inbox)

Comment: @ŁukaszL. no definitly no dub. I'm talking about the Android App not the web.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean smart phone notifications, or simply that rep changes are displayed in the app like messages are? There are two questions [being] closed a duplicates of this which ask for different things.