# Why do only answers or replies appear in the notification tab of Android SE app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications

Recently, I've entered SE desktop site for first time. I've seen the site notifies you when you lose/win reputation, when an edit has been accepted... etc.

Why do only answers and reply notifications appear in the notification bar of the SE Android app?

Why don't all the notifications appear in the notification bar?

Comment: I don't understand the Q. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @NVZ Of course.

Comment: The SE app for Android is nowhere near perfection. So it's possible that it has very limited features right now.

Comment: @NVZ Okay, now I understand. Maybe in the future, the SE app will be full featured as the web version, right?

Comment: If you're asking about reputation change feature request, then it has been asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202512/optional-android-notifications-for-reputation-changes. No response from the devs though

Comment: @AndrewT. That's what I was searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android spits out notifications for things in the *Inbox*, but not Achievements. It took me a while to figure this out as well, but anything that appears in this tab:

[image]

will result in a notification. Anything in this tab:

[image]

Will not.